# android call log

Tags: android

With the following codes, the call log displayed is empty.Why is that soo??

```
package fypj.c;

import java.security.Provider;
import java.util.ArrayList;   
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class c extends ListActivity {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   

        String[] column = new String[] {android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE};         
        int[] names = new int[] {R.id.CLName, R.id.CLDuration, R.id.CLType};         
        myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, column, names);         
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);  
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:id="@+id/CLName"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:id="@+id/CLType"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:id="@+id/CLDuration"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you please remove all that comments if they are not necessary?

Comment: how do you get `cursor`? And what is your main.xml?

Comment: i accidently deleted the line on the cursor 

Cursor cursor = 
getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); startManagingCursor(cursor);

Comment: i have jus added the xml codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d%29),

"This constructor is deprecated.
This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader. "

Try an alternative to rule out any problem with your code.

Comment: looking at the example from developer.android now.
shall try it, between thanks:)

Comment: i am nt soo sure how the loadermanager works.
They mention that the loader was introduced in Android 3.0, i am using 2.2.

Comment: now i jus the R.layout.main instead there is the textview but the values displayed are like 117,10,25 
its suppose to show the contact's name, type and duration

Comment: I would suggest starting with a working sample app and understand what is required first. [Here's one](http://dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/25-android-tutorial-call-logs)